# Not understanding unexplained notation

Tags: functional-analysis, notation

I am reading a set of lecture notes on Functional Analysis and I have come across a not introduced notation when reading a corollary of Hahn-Banach Extension Theorem. Could anybody please explain what does $S_{X^*}$ represent?

The corollary is the following:

Let $X$ be a normed vector space. For each $x_0 \in X$ there exists $f \in S_{X^*}$ such that $f(x_0) = \| x_0\|$. In particular, $\|x\| = \max\{ |f(x)| : \; f \in S_{X^*}\}$ for all $x\in X$.

I do not have access to notes of prerequisite courses and it is difficult to get in touch with the writer of the document.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any normed space $X$, $S_X$ usually denotes the unit sphere of $X$:
$$S_X=\{x\in X:\|x\|=1\}.$$
This result tells us that there is a functional $f\in X^*$ such that $|f(x)|\leq\|x\|$ for all $x\in X$, and $|f(x_0)|=\|x_0\|$.

Comment: Thank you! Superficially ignored that there is an S already for more "general" normed linear spaces! Thought it was something intrinsically related to functionals.